# Firestore chat app using Firebase-UI (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am trying to create a chat using the Firebase-UI library for Cloud Firestore.
[This](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo/database/firestore) github repository contains the relevant code which I am using.
The problem comes with the order of the query.

See that the query is specified as:

```
Query sChatQuery = sChatCollection.orderBy("timestamp").limit(50);
```

However, I am getting the oldest 50 messages, instead of the newest ones, in the correct order (from old to new). On the other hand, I can use the following query:

```
Query sChatQuery = sChatCollection.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(50);
```

and this retrieves the 50 newest messages, but in the wrong order (newest on top, oldest on bottom). Hence I do not know how to get this right.

I could locally reverse again the result from the query, but I cannot figure out how to do that (I have already gone through the FirebaseUI library with no luck).

**EDIT**

I have my `chat` subcollection for each event in my `events` collection:

`events/event_doc/chat/chat_doc`

[image]

And I would like to get the messages as follows:

```
Message 1
Message 2
Message 3
Message 4
...
```

With the default order I get the messages like shown above, but the `limit` instructions cuts the snapshots from 1 to 50, and the `Message 51` (the newest) is not being retrieved.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Query sChatQuery = sChatCollection.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).limit(50);`

Comment: Yes, and it seems this is the default order: `Query sChatQuery = sChatCollection.orderBy("timestamp").limit(50);`

Comment: Please add your database structure as a scrennshot and indicate the exact order that you want to get, with a concrete example.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you can use the following query:

```
Query sChatQuery = sChatCollection
    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("timestamp', desiredTime)
    .limit(50);
```

If you are using a `RecyclerView` to display data, the simplest way would be to use the following code:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

This approch will reverse you the order as you want.

Another approach would be to create your own adapter that extends `FirebaseListAdapter` and override `getItem()` method like this:

```
@Override
public HashMap getItem(int pos) {
    return super.getItem(getCount() - 1 - pos);
}
```

Another approach would be to get the data from the database, add it to a `Collection`, a `List` would be a good solution and then use `Collections.reverse(yourList);`.

Comment: Before posting the question I was already using the `setReverseLayout` trick, but it does not seem like the best solution. About the last approach you mention, How can I do that with the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`?