# How to retrieve limited documents in firestore depending on the time they were added(For a chat app)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Basically I want to align the messages as they are supposed to be in the usual chat app.

**UPDATE:** Now messages are aligned properly in the recyclerview. But whenever I send the new message it puts them on the top of the other messages. And whenever I go back and come again to that activity messages are arranged properly(even the top ones).

I just want the message which I send to show up at the bottom. Any help will be appreciated.

```
mLinearLayout.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Then:

```
 private void loadmessage() {
    mFirestore.collection("Users").orderBy("Timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(10).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                            @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w("TAG", "listen:error", e);
                return;
            }

            for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                switch (dc.getType()) {
                    case ADDED:
                        Message message = dc.getDocument().toObject(Message.class);
                        messageList.add(message);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(messageList.size()-10);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032569/firestore-chat-app-using-firebase-ui-android) is the same case scenario and it has the answer too. So in case anyone looking for the answer.

And [This](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo/database/firestore) is the github repository for the features of the firestore chat app.

Answer (score 0):

You should continue retrieving the information as you are currently doing, and then invert the order on client side, it isn't an expensive task, and trying to do what you want in Firestore is not implemented yet.

After retrieving the list, you can do something like:

```
 Collections.reverse(messageList.clone());
```

Comment: I want limited chat messages to be in order with the time when I send the message just like the simple chat app. This is to add pagination afterwards.

Comment: So just to be clear: your current functionality `orderBy("Timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).limit(10)` works for you?

Comment: This query gives the first 10 documents according to the time they were added. As soon as I type the 11th message, it does not show that document. If I use `DESCENDING` then it shows the latest required documents but in reverse order.

Comment: Firestore has a [built-in pagination functionality](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) that you can take a look at.