# How to put the last document added to the bottom of recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

Basically I want to align the messages as they are supposed to be in the usual chat app.

Now messages are aligned properly in the `RecyclerView`. But whenever I send the new message it puts them on the top of the other messages. And whenever I go back and come again to that activity messages are arranged properly(even the top ones).

I just want the message which I send to show up at the bottom. Any help will be appreciated

```
mLinearLayout.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Then:

```
private void loadmessage() {
mFirestore.collection("Users").orderBy("Timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(10).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w("TAG", "listen:error", e);
            return;
        }

        for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
            switch (dc.getType()) {
                case ADDED:
                    Message message = dc.getDocument().toObject(Message.class);
                    messageList.add(message);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(messageList.size()-10);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: are you using listview to show messages ?

Comment: I am using RecyclerView to show messages.

Comment: `mLinearLayout.setReverseLayout(true)` this will reverse the adapter content. Do you want that?

Comment: Yes. Reversing the recyclerView will show the chats in the required order (from older to new).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you need to change your query like this:

```
mFirestore.collection("Users")
    .orderBy("Timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .limit(10)
    .addSnapshotListener(/* ... */);
```

And your `RecyclerView` should look like this:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

This approch will reverse you the order as you want.

**Edit:**

You can verride the `getItem()` method to invert the item lookup like this:

```
@Override
public HashMap getItem(int pos) {
    return super.getItem(getCount() - 1 - pos);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it will only give the first 10 documents instead of last 10 documents.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Should be `DESCENDING` as in my updated answer and not `ASCENDING`. Does it work now?

Comment: I am using `DESCENDING` already. But as the layout is reversed, whenever I send the new message it puts them on the top instead at the bottom.

Comment: This is something new. Where is the `getItem()` method?

Comment: You need to override it inside your adapter class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176509/discussion-between-ashish-yadav-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: So if you are using a `RecyclerView` to display the items you are using for sure an adapter. Inside the adapter class just override the `getItem` method, right? ALT+INS in Android Studio find it and implement it.

Comment: Is there everything alright, have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032569/firestore-chat-app-using-firebase-ui-android) is the same case scenario and it has the answer too. So in case anyone looking for the answer. Alex has stated various ways to solve this type of condition.

And [This](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo/database/firestore) is the github repository for the features of the firestore chat app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messageList.size()-1);
 mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Same result. Just that it does not scroll to bottom now.

Comment: When ever you add new message then call to these lines. It will show the bottom new message at bottom..

Comment: I have recently done this in listView... and also checked with ReyclerView by using above line and it works for me.

Comment: It still shows the newly added message at the top. I am using `mLinearLayout.setReverseLayout(true);`. You know this right?

Comment: mLinearLayout.setReverseLayout(true); remove this line then try my code

Comment: Then it will work. But I want that too so as to show the chats in proper order (from older to new).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176503/discussion-between-opriday-and-ashish-yadav).